# Load document ready before images

Tags: jquery, image, document-ready, smooth-scrolling

I am using the Smooth Div Scroll plugin and I have heavy images in it...
in the top of my page I also have links, all my links have `margin-right:15px;`
and I have a simple jQuery code that cancels the `margin-right:15px;` from my last link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
    $('div.linksHolder a:last-child').css("margin-right","0");
     });
</script>
```

Now, in all my pages it works great! However in the page with the heavy images it takes a while until it loads the jQuery function above... and it looks weird that the link is down a line for a few seconds before the browser execute the code...

My question is: How can I load the function above before starting to load the images?

Sorry for my bad English and hope you understood my question.

Comment: Did you try jQuery Lazy Loading?

Comment: Why would you want js to do this? Why not just set it through css?

Comment: @jtheman because if I load it from the css it won't work with IE8

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you apply that setting from your stylesheet:

```
<style>
/* existing link styles here, then: */

div.linksHolder a:last-child {
    margin-right : 0px;
}
</style>
```

Apparently `:last-child` is [not supported in IE8 and older](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t35), but you could leave your jQuery code in place too to cover for that...

Comment: Yes, I _said_ that. What I'm suggesting is that it doesn't hurt to put it in your stylesheet anyway because at least that should solve the problem for other browsers, and if you leave the jQuery code in place that will make the adjustment in IE8 and older even if it doesn't happen as quickly as you'd like.